# How to keep the context of the response of the agent for the next dialog of the user in Dialogflow

Tags: webhooks, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am developing a Quiz bot with Dialogflow platform. When it is instructed to initiate the game, a question is generated from the webhook call and displayed to the user. A reference of that particular question is needed to be sent back with the user's answer to the webhook in order to validate the answer. I am finding it difficult to send back the reference of the previous response of the agent.

Any useful idea will be very much appreciated.

Intended scenario to develop as below.

```
Bot : Shall we begin?
User : Yes begin.
Bot : What is the highest mountain in the world? 
  A. Mount Everest
  B. Gyachung Kang
  C. MOunt Fuji
User : A
Bot : That is correct. Next question is : 
  First Afghan War took place in?
  A. 1833
  B. 1843
  C. 1839
User : B
Bot : That is incorrect. Your next question is...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it exactly! You'll use a Dialogflow [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services#contexts).

In your fulfillment, you'll create a context and set a parameter in the context to the identifier of the question you're asking. So that context might look something like

```
{
  name: "question",
  lifespan: 5,
  parameters: {
    questionNumber: 1
  }
}
```

When your webhook is called when you get an answer, you'll check the context to get the parameter with the question asked and can lookup and compare the answer. So when checking the answer we'll lookup the "question", determine that the question number was 1, look up in our question/answer table to determine the correct answer was A, and compare that to what the user said.

Comment: As i know so far, we can create contexts to what the user says and store the parameters in the memory. But how can we do that for the dialog that agent says? If you can clarify what 'In your fulfillment, you'll create a context and set a parameter in the context to the identifier of the question you're asking' means, it would be so helpful

Comment: It is difficult to provide any more details beyond the link I already provided. You haven't shown any code from your webhook, or even indicated what programming language or library you're using, so I can't provide any examples, but I've tried to broadly clarify a little.

Comment: i am using PHP in the webhook. From the Dialogflow end, is there any way to keep the reference to the previous dialog of the agent?

Comment: Yes thank you that makes sense. How can I set this 'questionNumber' to the context? Because the question is in the response of the agent. Say we require the 'questionNumber' field to be filled with the intent. But how to fill it without it including in the user's dialog?

Comment: The context would also be set in the response. I don't know how you're sending the response now, so I don't know what details I can tell you.